# Starting the simulator in XCode 9 (not headless)

Tags: ios, xcode, ios11, xcode9

I am trying to run both my `unit` and `ui` tests with `xcodebuild` like:

```
$ xcodebuild -scheme "MyAppScheme" -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 7 Plus,OS=11.0' build test CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="" CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO
```

The problem is that the simulator **doesn't start** but instead is running heedlessly.

I am aware of the so called "headless simulator" introduced in XCode 9. Any ideas of how to run the tests with `xcodebuild` and launch the emulator ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know there are no options to allow you to run the tests on a not headless Simulator.

However if a Simulator is already launched the tests will run on that Simulator instead of a headless one. So you can first launch the Simulator and then run the tests:

```
$ open /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app && xcodebuild -scheme "MyAppScheme" -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 7 Plus,OS=11.0' build test CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="" CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO
```